# MySQL NEW. values are empty in AFTER INSERT trigger

Tags: mysql

I've been searching for 2 days on this one.  I have a simple MySQL AFTER INSERT trigger to insert the new data into a 2nd table.  However, when I run the trigger the 2nd table has all blank fields, except the foreign key ID from the 1st table....all other fields are empty. It seems the NEW. values in the insert trigger are blank when they should not be.

FIRST TABLE WITH THE AFTER INSERT TRIGGER:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `joom_cck_store_form_smart_mail_forward` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `mailbox_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `domain_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `forward_email_address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mailbox_comment` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `forward_to_persons_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `MailboxName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

AFTER INSERT TRIGGER:

```
DELIMITER //

Create TRIGGER joom_cck_store_form_smart_mail_forward_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON joom_cck_store_form_smart_mail_forward FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   DECLARE zDBname varchar(100);

   -- Insert record into main smart mail forward system table
   INSERT INTO zEmailForward(source_id, mailbox_name, domain_name, comment_text, recipient_email_address, recipient_name) 
       VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.mailbox_name, NEW.domain_name, NEW.mailbox_comment, NEW.forward_email_address, NEW.forward_to_persons_name);

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

RESULT AFTER INSERTING A NEW ROW IN THE PRIMARY TABLE

The row in the primary table saves fine with all values filled in.  The AFTER INSERT trigger runs and inserts a row in the second table (zEmailForward).  However, only the source_id field from the prmary table has a value in the zEmailForward table; all other columns are blank in zEmailForward.  The NEW. values in the trigger are all blank, even though they should not be.

```
===================================================================
PRIMARY TABLE (joom_cck_store_form_smart_mail_forward) ROW:
===================================================================
id   MailboxName   domain_name   forward_email_address   mailbox_comment   forward_to_persons_name   
10   Test          domain.com    test@testemail.com      this is a test       Test Person

===================================================================
2nd TABLE (zEmailForward) ROW CREATED BY THE AFTER INSERT TRIGGER:
===================================================================
ID source_id   MailboxName   domain_name   recipient_email_address   comment_text   recipient_name   
1  10
```

So you can see the ID from joom_cck_store_form_smart_mail_forward copied to the source_id of zEmailForward field just fine....but all other fields in zEmailForward are blank.

===================================

## Database server information

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: Percona Server
Server version: 5.6.31-77.0-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 77.0, Revision 5c1061c
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

==================================================
Any ideas why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: I would guess that the trigger name already exists, so you are not running the trigger you think you are.  Try dropping the trigger and then re-creating it.

Comment: Thanks Gordon but the code above is pulled from the PHPMyAdmin trigger edit box so it is the current code.

Comment: It appears that you might be looking at a wrong table. Your `CREATE TABLE` statement has, among others, columns `mailbox_name` and `MailboxName`. But "PRIMARY TABLE ROW" only has `MailboxName`, and it goes first. Of course, maybe it's not a complete row but a result of your processing, but given the mystery at hand, it looks suspicious. If it's not a mistake, then please paste `SHOW CREATE` for the 2nd table. An example of the `INSERT` statement might also be useful.

Comment: The table does have both mailbox_name and MailboxName columns, but I only used MailboxName in the example above.  I'm guessing I have hit some strange bug in Percona MySQL so I posted on their forum too.  thanks

Comment: Update:  Further investigation shows that the issue may be this:  The web form adding the row seems to be temporarily inserting a blank row then updating it with the actual values.  This explains why only the primary key ID field is non-blank in the NEW. row of the after insert trigger.  I found this by creating an after update trigger that I can see firing when I add a new row with the web form.  Very odd.

Answer (score 1):

ANSWERED MYSELF:

In case it helps others here's the answer:

Further investigation shows that the issue was:

The web form adding the new row was temporarily inserting a blank row then updating it with the actual values in a 2nd step. This explains why only the primary key ID field is non-blank in the NEW. row of the after insert trigger. I found this by creating an after update trigger that I can see firing when I add a new row with the web form. Very odd and not sure why the form developer did it this way.